# Matriz no se muestra (Tokenizacion de string por delimitaciones (",")) C++

Tags: c++, string, bucle-for, matriz

tengo una pregunta bastante importante para mí y es llevar un texto tipo string a un chart o una matriz utilizando delimitadores y sin depender de archivos de texto externos al programa. El codigo que hice para llevar el string a la matriz separando el texto por el delimitador (",") es este:

```
std::string mvalores [50] [12];
//convetir string en tabla pasando las letras a char y luego designarlas a una casilla de la matriz concatenando la variable actual con el nuevo char hasta llegar al delimitador               

std::string from4 = ",";
std::string::size_type pos4 = 0;
std::string concatenacion;
int da = 0;
       
for (int fils = 0; fils <= 50; fils++){

    for (int cols = 0; cols <= 12; cols++){
    pos4 = DATA.find(from4, pos4) < std::string::npos;

        for (int da; da < pos4, da++;){          
        concatenacion = concatenacion + DATA[da];//designar concatenacion a matriz.
        } 

    mvalores [fils][cols] = concatenacion;
    std::replace(mvalores [fils][cols].begin(), mvalores [fils][cols].end(), ',', '\0');
    concatenacion = "";
    std::cout << mvalores [fils][cols] << std::endl;

    }
}
```

Los valores no se muestran en las casillas de la matriz... como si de nada se tratase, se muestra vacío todo.

Lo que hace el código es convertir los números y letras de mi string en un solo texto, concatenándose hasta llegar a la "," que es mi delimitador, luego lo concatenado se va pegando a mi matriz columna por columna hasta llegar a la columna 12, de ahi se salta a una nueva fila y sigue el mismo proceso.

Answer (score 0):

Aquí

```
pos4 = DATA.find(from4, pos4) < std::string::npos;
```

Fíjate que no estás guardando una posición sino, simplemente, un 1 o un 0.

Ese operador *menor que* realiza una operación booleana, por lo que el resultado final será `1`, si se ha encontrado la cadena, o `0` en caso contrario.

Esta línea realmente deberías dividirla en dos

```
pos4 = DATA.find(from4, pos4);

if (pos4 < std::string::npos)
{ \* ...  */ }
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, no me hubiera dado cuenta solo, espectacular y fantastico, te daria flechita arriba pero soy muy novato y estoy aprendiendo solo jajajajaja, sin profe :'(

Comment: @MatiasEspejo Para eso estamos, para ayudar ;) Por otro lado, para votar preguntas y/o respuestas, tienes unas flechas encima y debajo de los puntos asociados a dicho elemento (la pregunta o la respuesta). Flecha para arriba = voto positivo y flecha para abajo = voto negativo. Cuando elaboras una pregunta puedes marcar una respuesta con correcta. Para ello, debajo de la puntuación de cada respuesta tienes un tick que está en color gris. Click sobre el tick de la respuesta que quieras marcar como solución.